# Migration SBS 2008 > Windows Server 2016

Tags: migration, windows-server-2016, windows-sbs-2008

In process of migrating from an `Windows 2008 SBS` to a `Windows Server 2016`
Thus far I have

- installed `MS Server 2016`
- promoted it to be a Domain Controller

I came across this how-to [My company has outgrown SBS/Essentials. How do I migrate off?](https://serverfault.com/questions/821249/my-company-has-outgrown-sbs-essentials-how-do-i-migrate-off) and am wondering how to practically carry out these 3 parts

> 4. Migrate DHCP and Certificate Services off SBS (assuming you're using
>      them--be certain).

is it just add the DHCP role top the new machine and stop the service in the old one?

> 5. Migrate your file and printer shares off SBS and onto a non-DC
>      server (putting them on a DC isn't recommended).

1. fileshares are being migrated with some sort of `robocopy` command I believe. How do you practically migrate printer shares? Do I have to add the role `Print and Document Services` on the Server 2016 in order to do that?
2. we only have 1 server available, so I guess I'll just ignore that comment about putting shares on a non-DC server? Or would anyone recomend to keep the SBS running obly as a DC and DHCP Server? I guess sooner or later SBS 2008 will not be supported any longer. Also the SBS in question wasn't maintained really and likewise has quite some minor things not running well (WSUS i.e.) and therefore I was hopping to 'start fresh' on a new machine.

> 6. Migrate the FSMO roles off SBS. This will start your 21 day migration grace period

what are the practical steps to do that?

Also I thought the grace period would start with promoting the new Server to be a DC. Was that info (or my understanding of it) incorrect? I am prompted with a 'critical Alert' in the Dashboard of the new server about a "License Error FSMO Role Check" and tells me to *"Ensure that the FSMO roles are located on this server to prevent the server from shutting down"*

I believe this IS the sign of being into grace period giving be 21 days after promoting to DC to fix this problem?

Also another thing (which is not mentioned in the howto in question here whatsoever) is holding me back big time: Connecting client computers (not talking about user account, that goes automatically) to the new Server 2016 (through a tool called "Windows Server Esssentials Connector"). So I'm wondering whether this is even required?

Comment: There are too many questions in one post for me to even begin answering, but:  I migrated the printer shares by hand and wrote a script to repoint printers. Here are some links that will get you started with [DHCP](http://www.brycematheson.io/how-to-migrate-dhcp-from-windows-server-2008-to-2012-2016/), [Certificate Services](https://windorks.wordpress.com/2014/08/12/migrating-a-microsoft-pki/) and [migrating FSMO roles](https://www.petri.com/transferring_fsmo_roles). If the FSMO roles have ended up on the new server you can use that article to switch them back and postpone the grace period.

Comment: Also, my client computers "migrated themselves" through normal AD replication.